# How to apply overlay on navigation when clicked?

Tags: jquery, navigation, overlay

I used the fixed navigation from http://www.jqueryload.com. Restyled it and that works fine.

I tried to add a dark overlay when "navigatie" is clicked. I found several solutions here, but when I implement them, the script for the navigation does not work anymore. I think it's because of the solutions found here are also using 'this'. But I don't know how to rewrite them.
How can I add an overlay when the first li = navigatie is clicked? Thanks in advance
This is the code I use:

HTML

```
    <div id="nav" class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="#">Navigatie<span> <img src="/images/plus.gif" 
    width="12px" height="12px"  alt="plus" /></span></a>
    <ul>
    <li><a href="./index.php">Home</a></li>
    <li class="keukens"><a href="keukens.php">Keukens</a></li>       
    <li class="app"><a href="apparatuur.php">Apparatuur</a></li>
    <li class="interieur"><a href="interieur.php">Interieur</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a> 
    </ul>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
    #nav{float:left;}
    #nav ul{list-style-type:none; color:#000;}
    .menu{ font: 100% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif ;padding-top:100px;
    color:#000;height:30px;background-color:;}    
    .menu a:hover{background-color:;}
    .menu a {text-decoration: none;padding: 0;color:#000;outline:none;}
    .menu ul{list-style: none;margin:0;padding-left:10px;}
    .menu ul li{padding:0;float:left;}
    .menu ul li ul li{padding:0;float:none;margin: 0 0 0 0px;width:100%;}
    .menu ul li ul{position: relatieve;border: 0px solid #C3D1EC;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px #CCCCCC;margin-top: -1px; display:none;
    padding:20px 0px 0px 0px;}
    .active ul{display:block !important;}
    .active a{border: 0px solid #C3D1EC;border-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 0px 0px #CCCCCC;display: block;height: 29px;
    padding: 0 0;position:relative;z-index: 1;}
    .active a:hover{background-color:#000;color:#CCC;}
    .sub{ left:10px;position: absolute; top:180px;}
```

JQUERY:

```
    (function($){
    $.fn.fixedMenu=function(){
    return this.each(function(){
        var menu= $(this);
        menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(){
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
        })
    });

}  
    })

    (jQuery);
```

The working version can be found here http://www.tossdesign.nl

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it's the $(this) which is wrong.

Do this instead:

```
 var menu= $('#nav');
```

Also double check you have valid HTML for your menu structure.
I had to copy the orginal html from the link you gave to get it to work.

I used this code for the js

```
 var menu= $('#nav');
    menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(){
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
            $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
        }
        else{
            $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        }
    })
```

for reference, this was the html:

```
   <ul>
     <li class="active">
 <a href="#">Navigatie<span> <img width="12px" height="12px" alt="plus" src="/images/plus.gif"></span></a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="./index.php">Home</a></li>
           <li class="keukens"><a href="keukens.php">Keukens</a></li>       
           <li class="app"><a href="apparatuur.php">Apparatuur</a></li>
           <li class="interieur"><a href="interieur.php">Interieur</a></li>
            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a> 
           </li>
        </ul>
     </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: If I add a div with the id "overlay" to the html and proper css of cource. How do I incorporate these lines in the script, so that when the active li is clicked the overlay shows and when the active class is removed the overlay dissapeares. 
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function()
        $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');

Comment: No, the problem stay's the same. I'm trying to achieve an effect like this. [http://jsfiddle.net/dwrUj/]

Comment: OK, I'm still not 100% sure what you want, but see if this is it: http://jsfiddle.net/RYJQ2/

Comment: That looks great but is not what I mean, I made a example picture, you can find it here: http://www.tossdesign.nl/php_site/overlay.png the php_site is to test changes.